# Are there any good videos out there on Java Design Patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, video

My team would like to spend some time at lunch learning design patterns.  Previously, we watched some videos on Javascript which we found very useful as a way to start discussions.  We would like to do the same thing with design patterns so that we don't have to spend a lot of time (outside of work) researching individual patterns in order to give a presentation.

I did a little searching and came up fairly empty handed.  Any help would be appreciated.  It doesn't even have to be a video, even something that we can listen to (maybe a book on tape even).

Answer (score 4):

Well, it is a book... but it is great. [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

Answer (score 0):

[Youtube.com](http://youtube.com) has search capabilities. Try ["java design patterns"](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=java+design+patterns).